# How to add string value in register w.r.t date

Tags: windows, registry

I want add an some value in windows registry w.r.t date for eg. i have one example which show string value=reg and value =4022299. This value is actually represents 1 Nov 2059, i don't know from where i can generate different numbers for different dates and so i can add to my registry.

Can anyone help me  plz?
Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric value represents a number of units-of-time from an epoc to the specified date and time (note that date and time are the same thing in computers).

A common unit is the second, aka "Unix time" (the number of seconds since 1st of January 1970 UTC). .NET uses "Ticks" which are 100 nanoseconds. You can also use miliseconds.

The value 4022299, if it's seconds and Unix time, actually represents a date in February 1970, so I don't know what algorithm is in use there.

I suggest you use Unix time for compatibility purposes. This is the code you need to generate a Unix time value:

```
public static Int32 GetUnixTimeStamp(DateTime date) {

    DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return (date - epochStart).Ticks * 100;
}
```

Used like so:

```
DateTime something = new DateTime( 2059, 11, 1 );
Int32 unixTime = GetUnixTimeStamp( something );
```

To add it to the registry:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SomeKey\\SomeValue", unixTime);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific plz, as i am not an .net/c# programmer

Comment: Your are right,i  don't know what algorithm he may have used,so i think i should prefer unix time conversion and try it with that.

Comment: One  more thing to ask, if i add epoch timestamp(seconds) and add that value to registry will that time work for me?

Comment: I just meant to say do these time conversion works in registry.